# how to calculate data at daily weekly and monthly granularity in one sql

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have data in this format on S3
I am using athena to generate aggregate results after join on 2 key columns

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCUCe.png]

**Requirement -**

At country level, I have to calculate count of events at daily, weekly and monthly level
So for japan in month of oct two events, weekly  one event should show as result.

**Expected result -**

when i join on country and event_date == transaction_date

[image]
how do I do the same in SQL

Comment: (1) Please show us the results that you want, as tabular text (2) Please tag your question with the database you are running: MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, ...?

Comment: Do you need to group by country or country and event_date ? If both columns are used then you return more than one row, if only country is the case then why 20201010 returns only. Btw, what's the data type of event_date which should be date but seems like a string type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If I am following your question you can use window functions in a subquery and then filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by eventdate) as day_count,
             count(*) over (partition by week) as week_count,
             count(*) over (partition by month) as month_count
      from t
     ) t
where eventdate = :transactiondate
```